# What's the difference between accessing the text theme via .of(context) method instead of statically?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter we can write our ThemeData in two ways,

1: As variable
2: As a method

```dart
final lightThemeData = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  primaryColor: primaryColor,
  textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
    ThemeData.light().textTheme,
  ),
  elevatedButtonTheme: elevatedButtonThemeData,
  colorScheme: ThemeData.light()
      .colorScheme
      .copyWith(secondary: secondaryColorLightTheme),
);
```

```dart
ThemeData buildThemeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: primaryColor,
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
      Theme.of(context).textTheme,
    ),
    elevatedButtonTheme: elevatedButtonThemeData,
    colorScheme: Theme.of(context)
        .colorScheme
        .copyWith(secondary: secondaryColorLightTheme),
  );
}
```

[Check the image for more clear explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCPOe.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no better way here since the two snippets have different behaviors:

- In the first one, the theme is independent from where it's used.
- In the second snippet, the theme inherits from the ambient theme because of the Theme.of(context).

But the context variant is significantly better

Because with the "create a new theme" variant, there's no single source of truth for the theme. Theming is all over the place